# Finding top ten requestors for top ten sites with bash

Tags: bash

So I have an apache.log file that I have found the top ten requested sites for using the following command:

```
cat apache.log  | awk '{print  $7} ' | awk '/.php$/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

Now that I have found the top ten sites, I would like to find the top requesting IP for each site, the IPs are listed in column ""1"" within the file. How do I do that?

Comment: Please, post some sample data (text, not images) with the expected output. Also, try to format it properly using the editor's help or my example. Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: BTW, `awk '/.php$/ { print $7 }' <apache.log` does the work of the first three pipeline elements, far more efficiently than using a separate command for each piece. (There's no reason `awk` couldn't be used to replace the rest of it either while keeping it to just one command with an awk script that does the sorting and counting, but that wouldn't fit as easily in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a sample line of log, with modified IPs and all? Just asking for the format (would have commented but need 50 reputation, so I'll blindly answer for now).

The command you want to use is something like:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Here, we suppose that you want the first (f)ield and that each field is (d)elimited by spaces.

Comment: 10.10.10.0 - - [31/Oct/1994:15:16:38 +0000] "DELETE /printer/remove.php HTTP/1.1" 200 52893

Comment: Then yes, just add `| cut -d ' ' -f 1` at the end of your command and it'll work. 

If it is a script you run often, I recommend you trying to optimize your first command (awk 'pattern' file, instead of using cat | awk, etc)  
https://shellcheck.net is a great resource.

Comment: @jeffreyanderson, edit that sample input into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To get the top ten requesting ips in a [common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) file you could do:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 apache.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 10 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the top 10 IP occurrences in `apache.log`, you can use something similar to the following:

```
awk '$7 ~ /.php$/{top[$1]++} END {for (i in top) printf "%6d - %s\n", top[i], i}' apache.log | 
sort -r -n | 
head -n10
```

Where `awk` creates an array indexed by IP holding the number of times each IP is found accessing a `.php` file. In the `END` rule, you simply output the number of occurrences and the IP and pipe the output to `sort -r -n` to reverse sort numeric. Then pipe to `head -n10` to take the top 10.

Your output would resemble:

```
   622 - 72.180.70.46
     8 - 47.90.246.235
     8 - 129.211.6.66
     4 - 159.65.24.22
     2 - 192.168.6.104
     1 - 52.237.38.163
     1 - 198.199.83.39
     1 - 192.99.36.177
     1 - 18.222.26.24
     1 - 167.99.212.214
```

(you can adjust the `printf` output format as desired)